# Llenar un id o data-request-url con X dato. jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

Tengo el siguiente `div` en el la pagina a mostrar, el cual tiene el `data-request-url` (puede ser tambien un id) vacio:

```
<div class="estatusActivo" data-request-url=""></div>
```

Cual quiero rellenar eso con un `true` o un `false`, cual seria la mejor opcion de hacerlo, estoy intentando algo asi, pero no funciona:

```
$('.statusActivo').data('request-url').val(true);
```

Comment: La forma correcta de hacerlo es `$('.statusActivo').data('request-url',true);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varios errores:

1. No estás referenciando bien la clase en JS, la estás llamando `statusActivo` pero en el `div` se llama `estatusActivo`
2. Si revisas [la documentación](https://api.jquery.com/data/) verás que la forma de asignar valores es así:

   ```
    $( "body" ).data( "foo", 52 );
   ```

Aplicando esto a tu código, sería de este modo:

```js
$('.estatusActivo').data('request-url',true);
var status=$('.estatusActivo').data('request-url');
console.log(status);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="estatusActivo" data-request-url=""></div>
```